# how easy is it to install and american light in the UK?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, light

I am looking to buy [this light](https://www.grandbrass.com/item/fxla01/) from the US.  Keen to understand if this is possible and what I would need to install it.  Many thanks M

Comment: Most of these parts are available in the lamp repair/parts section of hardware stores here in the US. Maybe you can find UK equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

Issues

- Bulbs will be 120V not 240V and will die as soon as connected. In worst case may shower you with broken glass (unlikely but a remote possibility). You will have to fit UK 240V light bulbs instead - they are available with Edison Screw fitting (marked ES or E27).
- Fitting won't conform to UK standards. This shouldn't be an issue, legally, as you are not reselling them.

  - The kit appears to contain exposed extraneous metal parts that are not earthed - this is regarded as unsafe in the UK and contravenes UK standards. I would drill and tap for screwed earth connection and check for low resistance path from tips of metal parts back to new earth connection.
  - Kit includes US wire nuts. Not used in UK, probably rated for 120V not 240V. Better to replace with a set of connectors rated for UK use.
  - Kit includes wire. Insulation may only be rated for 120V not 240V. Might be better to replace with wire rated for 240V.
- Is designed to mount to US ceiling boxes - you might need to improvise.
- It might be worth checking with your home insurance company whether they will cover fire or accidents related to this fitting.

Comment: Another solution would be to wire it as a drop light plug in type, plug it into a 240v to 120v converter.

Comment: US fixture (TFN/TFFN) wire is rated for 600V (it routinely gets exposed to well upwards of 240V in fluorescent lamp applications).  I would change out the connectors, though.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to rewire in series?

perhaps pair the bulbs in series then run each pair in parallel?

Can we engineer a solution?